# Duplicate item records in SOLR index (web)

Tags: solr, indexing, versions

We have a strange issue on our UAT environment where duplicate records are being returned for a single content item in a new web index we have created and both are marked with 'latestversion:true' (which this means both records get through our query filters).

The SOLR records contain the following fields:

**SOLR record 1:**

__created_by_s: sitecore\user1
__smallupdateddate_tdt: 2019-05-30T16:39:57Z
version_im: [10]
_creator: sitecore\user1
__smallcreateddate_tdt: 2019-05-30T14:15:34Z
_latestversion: true
_language: en-GB
*version*: 1635047913152315400

**SOLR record 2:**

__created_by_s: sitecore\user2
__smallupdateddate_tdt: 2019-05-31T13:05:56Z
version_im: [12]
_creator: sitecore\user2
__smallcreateddate_tdt: 2019-05-31T13:03:56Z
_latestversion: true
_language: en-GB
*version*: 1635055446459940900

Looking at the item versions in master and web shows the following:

[image: Master database versions]
[image: Web database version]

The web version is higher than the versions in master. And there is no version 10 in the web database.

Is this down to the item having become corrupt? Or could it be attributed to something else?

Comment: Is there `_uniqueid` field in the documents? Is it unique?

Comment: There is a _uniqueid field, they are different based on the version number:

_uniqueid: sitecore://web/{3e0eaab6-0957-4d9c-98ac-eee39769fe1d}?lang=en-gb&ver=10&ndx=web_navigation_index

_uniqueid: sitecore://web/{3e0eaab6-0957-4d9c-98ac-eee39769fe1d}?lang=en-gb&ver=12&ndx=web_navigation_index

Comment: It looks like the index is corrupted for some reason. Try rebuilding index and see if the issue persists.